# Collection view header is not visible runtime

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview

I'm using stock collection view controller and just enabled header reusable view in storyboard.

[image]

However, on runtime I don't see that title label. Question is do I have to implement something in order to see the label created in storyboard? If not, what may cause it not to be visible? I can see all cells runtime, can see also the space occupied by header reusable view. However, it's empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to implement

```
collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:
```

in order to get section views. This method is part of the datasource of the collectionView